# Enable cross-project debugging in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a C/C++ solution comprised of several projects in VS2010. The start-up project is where `main()` locates and it will generate `.exe` file, while the others are core algorithms which will generate `.dll` files. When I debug the whole solution, sometimes it cannot go into the `.dll` projects but after rebuilding the whole solution, the problem can be temporarily  solved; However after building one or more times, the problem returns.

Currently I have to rebuild the whole solution every time I modify the code, but it's so bothering. Is there any way that I can avoid such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is happening only in the case when some project in your solution is changed or the .exe present in release or debug directory is different from the code. So, make sure like you are `building each project successfully after modifying` it.
And it is always good to debug in `DEBUG` mode to get exact result.

Answer (score 0):

Everal things you could try: Make sure all projects which need to be rebuilt after a change indeed are. So make sure the project dependencies are set correctly and that the startup project is the exe project.

As second option, you could allow the debugger to show source even if it does not match the code exactly (look for something named "source files must match original exactly" or similar in Options->Debugging->General). Be aware that it might indeed happen that your changes are not reflected in the program if this is needed.